# create new server Tomcat7 in Eclipse

Tags: 12.04, server, eclipse, tomcat

I installed tomcat7 by the command `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`. So far so good I wanted to create a new server in eclipse with tomcat7 and went to preferences -> servers -> runtime environments and added tomcat7 with the path "/usr/share/tomcat7" which was set by default. I created a project with dynamic web content where tomcat7 was already selected. I switched to the Java EE perspective and to the server view. It was no server defined so I wanted to define one with the new server wizard which didn't allow me to create a new tomcat7 server with the message "cannot create a server using the selected type".

So I searched the solution in google and found
[this blog](http://hariprasad.info/cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-eclipse-tomcat/)

I couldn't find the .metadata folder in my workspace, therefore I created a new workspace since my other workspace seems to be corrupt. Doing that and the steps 1 to 3 in the blog didn't solve my problem.

I hope anyone of you could help me out.

Further information:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Eclipse Indigo JEE 3.7
- Tomcat 7

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I just tryed to remove the tomcat7 installation but it throws me following error:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get remove tomcat7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libcommons-collections3-java libecj-java libcommons-pool-java authbind
tomcat7-common libtomcat7-java libcommons-dbcp-java libservlet3.0-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
tomcat7
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 356 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 512973 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing tomcat7 ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/tomcat7.prerm: 373: .: 3: Too many open files
dpkg: error processing tomcat7 (--remove):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                      /var/lib/dpkg/info/tomcat7.config: 373: .: 4: Too many open files
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
tomcat7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423593/eclipse-4-2-juno-cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-in-tomcat-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISSUE#1
**.metadata** folder is hidden and it's placed in directory that you specified as your 'workspace' directory while opening Eclipse for the first time.

ISSUE#2
You tried to remove some dependant package while one of the process was active, probably tomcat server was started from Eclipse.